# Как взять из функции определенное значение Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Есть функция в пакете `Telebot` - `send_message`, она отправляет сообщение пользователю, и если ее заключить в переменную, допустим это будет `x`, она будет в себе хранить информацию:

```
{'content_type': 'text', 'message_id': 398, 'from_user': {'id': 742445869, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'Название бота', 'username': 'Bot', 'last_name': None, 'language_code': None}, 'date': 1570243933, 'chat': {'type': 'private', 'last_name': None, 'first_name': 'NickUser', 'username': 'nikUser', 'id': 936271645, 'title': None, 'all_members_are_administrators': None, 'photo': None, 'description': None, 'invite_link': None, 'pinned_message': None, 'sticker_set_name': None, 'can_set_sticker_set': None}, 'forward_from_chat': None, 'forward_from': None, 'forward_date': None, 'reply_to_message': None, 'edit_date': None, 'media_group_id': None, 'author_signature': None, 'text': 'Текст', 'entities': None, 'caption_entities': None, 'audio': None, 'document': None, 'photo': None, 'sticker': None, 'video': None, 'video_note': None, 'voice': None, 'caption': None, 'contact': None, 'location': None, 'venue': None, 'new_chat_member': None, 'new_chat_members': None, 'left_chat_member': None, 'new_chat_title': None, 'new_chat_photo': None, 'delete_chat_photo': None, 'group_chat_created': None, 'supergroup_chat_created': None, 'channel_chat_created': None, 'migrate_to_chat_id': None, 'migrate_from_chat_id': None, 'pinned_message': None, 'invoice': None, 'successful_payment': None, 'connected_website': None, 'json': {'message_id': 398, 'from': {'id': 742445869, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'Название бота', 'username': 'MissionX_bot'}, 'chat': {'id': 936271645, 'first_name': 'userName', 'username': 'idUser', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1570243933, 'text': 'Текст'}}
```

Как можно запросить из переменной `x` информацию с номером `0` или `content_type`

Если нужно, то держите код для проверки:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("Ваш токен, который получите у @BotFather")

# Бот будет реагировать только на команду /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def send_message(message):
    if message.text.lower() == "/start":
        x = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                        "Привет")

        print(x)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Функции не содержат информацию, они возвращают значения. В переменную x не "заключена" функция, а записан результат ее вызова. Почитайте вот это хотя бы: [Функции и их аргументы](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/vse-o-funkciyax-i-ix-argumentax.html).

Comment: @insolor, я понял что они возвращают значения, просто не понял, можно ли получить значение из всего текста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас многое напутано в вопросе, функции, переменные.

Попробуйте так:

```
data = bot.send_message()
print(data["message_id"])
```

Comment: К сожалению, не работает такой метод

Comment: Фраза "не работает" довольно бесполезна, потому что не говорит, что именно и почему не работает.

Comment: Ошибка такая же как и раньше: `TypeError: 'Message' object does not support indexing`

Comment: Значит вам нужно разобраться, что чем является и соответствующим образом отредактировать вопрос.

Comment: Отредактировал, надеюсь более понятно чем в прошлый раз

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку send_message - словарь и атрибут объекта bot, достаточно обратиться к нему, как к объекту словаря:

```
bot.send_message['message_id']
```

Comment: Нет, не получается таким способом.
Что я пытался сделать:
1. Ошибка: `TypeError: 'Message' object does not support indexing`
1.1 Код: `messId = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                                "   Текст",
                                parse_mode="Markdown",
                                reply_markup=kbProfile)
                print(messId[0])`

2. Ошибка: `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`
2.2  Код:
messId = bot.send_message["message_id"]
print(messId)`

Comment: Значит в вопросе написано неправильно, и в send_message хранится не то, что вы написали. Судя по ошибке, это функция, а не переменная.

Comment: @Эникейщик, да, это функция. Но она содержит определенную информацию которую я даже указывал в вопросе. Мне необходимо получить из нее пункт с `message_id`, но не знаю как. Разве это невозможно?

Comment: Функция не может содержать информацию.